# How to copy references in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

I've got two Classes 'Method' and 'BackendMethod' which are in a one-to-many-relationship. I used the mappedBy-annotation on the Set of 'Methods' in BackentMethod.java.

I made a copy of the instance methodOriginal  called methodCopy and persisted it.
Now I want to have all BackendMethods which are referenced by methodOriginal to be referenced as well by methodCopy.

I don't want to copy them, just assign them to the new 'Method' again.

When I just assign them to them like this:

```
methodCopy.setBackendMethoden(methodOriginal.getBackendMethoden()));
```

I get a HibernateException:

> HibernateException: Found shared references to a collection: Method.backendMethoden

When I copy the whole set like this:

```
methodCopy.setBackendMethoden(new HashSet<Backend>(methodOriginal.getBackendMethoden())));
methodCopy.persist();
```

the set will be null afterwards.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you tries the below answers? I did not see any comments or acceptance on them.Tank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't want to copy them, just assign them to the new 'Method' again.

This won't work, because you have defined the relation between method and backendMethod as oneToMany. One BackendMethod entity can only be referenced by one Method (original) entity. If you want the same set of backendMethods for a MethodCopy, then you need a set of new backendMethod objects. In this case those backendmethod entities are duplicated in your database (with different PKs of course).

Or you can change the relationship to manytomany.

Answer (score 0):

When you copy reference in hibernate, always remember to **set the id values and relationsship values to null.** Here is what I usually do,

So, You need to iterate over the `methodOriginal.getBackendMethoden()` and set the reference and `ids` to `null`, and then set it to the `methodCopy`.

Also make sure that the `methodCopy`s and  id value is `null`.

Then this will be treated as a new objects and will be persisted.